# Benefits of O-ring collar over D-ring?

Tags: dogs, collar

What are the benefits of an O-ring collar over a traditional flat collar with a D-ring (if any)?

**O-ring collar**

[image]

**D-ring collar**

[image]

Comment: Maybe not everybody can imagine what you speak about. You could add a picture of both types to be more specific and get more precise answers...

Comment: I assume that the lash will be connected to the O ring in the red collar? If true, then in case of a breaking ring, the dog will not only loose the leash and owner, but also the collar and tag...

Comment: Contact the manufacturer of the collar with the additional ring and ask them what advantages they claim it has.  Then decide whether you agree.

Comment: Practically you'd always have the buckled side, and anything on the d ring in front, which can be a bit of a pain sometimes.